# AngularJS set select option from db

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been able to get the default value selected using the below. However, I am not sure how to set the value to the one previously selcted by the user for the object they are reviewing. If the default value matches their selection, then great it is fine.  However, if the default is different how can I make sure the select is showing the item that that they picked? For example, they have selected item [2] in the drop down not the default [0]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
select ng-init="part.PartType = partTypes[0]" class="form-control" data-ng-model="part.PartType" data-ng-options="p for p in partTypes" required></select>
</div>
```

I wouldn't doubt there was something obvious I am missing. I am just not sure what to set in order to display the previously selected value that is being returned from the db.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, S.

Comment: Why not set the default value in the controller?

Comment: Set value of ng-model variable to your selected item.

Comment: Thanks guys I will try that. I am new to Angular and figured I was missing something obvious. I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angularjs is 2 way bounded as in variables you should be able to set it in the controller